# Android Autocomplete Edittext setError shows when not called

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

in my project i have a Autocomplete Edittext with a list of values to chose from. 
If the user enters something that is not in that list there should be a Error shown. This works fine so far , the problem is that the error is also shown when the user (correctly) picks a item from the list. So when correctly picked both the if and else statement are executed.

Any Solutions?

```
for(int i = 0; i < countries.length; i ++) {
    if(citySelected.equals(countries[i])) {
        ServiceDatabase.getCity = citySelected;

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchService.this, ServiceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        int ecolor = Color.BLACK; // whatever color you want
        String estring = "Bitte wähle eine Stadt aus der Liste aus";
        ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
        SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
        ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);

        autoCompleteTextViewCity.setError(ssbuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor your `for` loop.

Currently it's checking the input against **every** city and if it doesn't match **any one of them**, then `setError` is called.

A potential solution would be something like:

```
if (Arrays.asList(countries).contains(ServiceDatabase.citySelected)) {
    // Start SearchService...
} else {
    // call setError on the TextView
}
```